# PHP echoing out code in tags?

Tags: php, mysqli

for some reason unless im overlooking something, This block of code here:

```
<?
include_once("connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_title ASC";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
$categories ="";
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['category_title'];
        $description = $row['category_decription'];
        $categories .= "<a href='#' class='cat_links'>".$title." - <font size='-1'>".$description."</font></a>";
    }
    echo $categories;
} else {

    echo"<p>There are no categories available yet.</p>";
}

?>
```

Seems to echo this out onto the page:

> 0) { while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ $id = $row['id']; $title = $row['category_title']; $description = $row['category_decription']; $categories .= "".$title." - ".$description.""; } echo $categories; } else { echo"
>   There are no categories available yet.
>
> "; } ?>

What have i done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: opening tag should be `<?php` your short tags are probably disabled.

Comment: Isn't opening tag should be `<?php` instead of `<?` ..

Comment: [Here is a SO question on short tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: Oh god, I cant believe ive overlooked that.. Thank you so much! xD

Answer (score 0):

Change your tags from `<?` to `<?php`. Short tags can be [disabled via a configuration setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), and are often turned off in production.